# Dúvida em exercício em C - leitura com fgets

Tags: c, string

Boa noite, eu estou aprendendo linguagem C através do livro do Luis Damas. Tem um exercício dele que o programa não está terminando na condição.

Eu estou usando linux então eu tive que mudar a função `gets()` para `fgets()`, não sei se o código precisa de mais alguma modificação para funcionar no Linux. Como mostra o código, se eu não entrasse com algum caractere o programa deveria terminar, porém ele não está terminando.

Outra coisa é que a saída está pulando uma linha, não está escrevendo o Nome,Sobrenome numa linha só.

Código que tenho:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DIM 20
#define SEP_NOME ","

int main()
{
    char Nome[DIM+1], Sobrenome[DIM+1],Completo[2*DIM+1];
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Nome: "); fgets(Nome, DIM+1, stdin);
        if(strlen(Nome)==0) break; /* Terminar o programa */
        /* Colocar o Sobrenome, Nome na string Completo */
        printf("Sobrenome: "); fgets(Sobrenome, DIM+1, stdin);
        strcpy(Completo,Sobrenome); /* Copiar sobrenome */
        strcat(Completo,SEP_NOME); /* Juntar separador */
        strcat(Completo,Nome); /* Juntar o prim. Nome */
        puts(Completo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu possuo esse livro, muito bom por sinal. Poderia me dizer onde se encontra o exercício?

Comment: É o prog0705 eu estou lendo através do sistema online da faculdade, aqui é a pagina 163.No Capitulo 7.

Comment: Olha, eu testei o programa exatamente como no livro, apenas inclui o header string.h (que não estava no livro) e funcionou perfeitamente. Só que estou usando o Windows 7 x64, alguns dias atrás, removi o Linux do PC, então não tem como eu testar. Mas no Windows, estou usando o GCC 8.1.0.

Comment: As funções gets e fgets são um pouco diferentes. Apesar de não ser recomendável a utilização da função gets, para exercícios simples como este você pode utiliza-la. A fgets considerará como caractere válido da string o caractere '\n' que sinaliza o final da entrada e pode limitar a quantidade de caracteres lidos. No seu caso você precisa eliminar este '\n' final que está forçando a quebra de linha.

Answer (score 2):

Os dois problemas são o mesmo na verdade, que é o facto do `fgets` deixar a quebra de linha na string lida. Por esse motivo, o `if` que testa se tem tamanho 0 nunca vai funcionar pois tem sempre pelo menos um caratere, a quebra de linha, e consequentemente vai quebrar entre os dois nomes quando tentar mostrar na tela.

Tem várias formas de resolver o problema, mas uma das mais diretas é através da função [`strspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strspn) que procura uma string dentro de outra. No caso você quer procurar pelo `\n` para colocar o terminador no seu lugar e se não houver coloca no fim.

Código com as quebras de linhas removidas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DIM 20
#define SEP_NOME ","

int main()
{
    char Nome[DIM+1], Sobrenome[DIM+1],Completo[2*DIM+1];
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Nome: "); 
        fgets(Nome, DIM+1, stdin);
        Nome[strcspn(Nome, "\n")] = '\0'; /* Remover quebra no nome*/
        if(strlen(Nome)==0) break; 

        printf("Sobrenome: "); 
        fgets(Sobrenome, DIM+1, stdin);
        Sobrenome[strcspn(Sobrenome, "\n")] = '\0'; /* Remover quebra no sobrenome */
        strcpy(Completo,Sobrenome); 
        strcat(Completo,SEP_NOME); 
        strcat(Completo,Nome); 
        puts(Completo);
    }
}
```

[Veja no Ideone a funcionar](https://ideone.com/AVO1yW)

Se utilizar `gets` ao invés de `fgets` não tem o mesmo problema, pois o `gets` não deixa a quebra de linha dentro da string, mas `gets` é desaconselhado pois apenas termina a leitura quando acha quebra de linha. Isso faz com que o usuário possa colocar mais carateres que o tamanho da string que você definiu e assim criar um *buffer overflow attack*.

Como nota final, o código vai rodar tanto em windows como em linux sem ter que fazer qualquer ajuste.